# print message when read timeout occur

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I am using pyserial to read sensor data through USB. But, sometimes the sensor does not send any data and it needs to be restarted. I found, we can use timeout, if for a certain time, the `read()` function of `pyserial` can not read. But, it does not work as I expected. I used the following code snippet for example:

```
ser=serial.Serial(port=addr, timeout=4)
while True:
    try:
        print(ser.read(size=5))
    except:
        print('not ok, restart!')
```

I was expecting, after `4` seconds, the except will be triggered. But that is not the case. After `4` seconds, printing null of length zero. This repeats each 4 seconds until restart.
How does my code sense that the time out happened and a certain massage needs to be printed?
I can also check the length `len(ser.read(size=5))` and do print the restart massage but problem will be even there is no timeout and the length will be calculated. That might hurt the performance. There should be some other better way.
Also, I can not use `serial.SerialTimeoutException`, because according to the doc:

```
Exception that is raised on write timeouts
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyserial does not trigger an exception on a read timeout, it just moves on.
What you could try instead is write a condition the check if the output length is zero

```
ser=serial.Serial(port=addr, timeout=4)
while True:
output = ser.read(size5)
if len(output) == 0:
   print('not ok, restart!')
else:
   print(output)
```